#  Is there a way to turn off the rMBP display with an external monitor plugged in, without closing the lid?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Turn off internal display without closing lid](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64449/turn-off-internal-display-without-closing-lid)

I use my retina MacBook Pro with an external monitor, but the area above the function keys gets pretty hot, especially when playing video. I'm kind of worried about the heat damaging the screen and was wondering if there was a way to turn off the laptop screen without closing the lid.

Right now, I'm just turning the brightness all the way down but it seems pointless to render 2880x1800 on the laptop screen without actually using it.